# str.split(r'\n') doesn't split a string on a newline character in a raw string literal as expected

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Suppose I have a string `s = hi\nhellon\whatsup` and I want to split it.

If I use `s.split('\n')`, I get the expected output:

```
['hi', 'hello', 'whatsup']
```

However, if I use `re.split('\n', s)`, it is actually `re.split(r'\n', s) and I also get the same output:

```
['hi', 'hello', 'whatsup']
```

Why does splitting on a raw string literal with `re.split()` work?

What is this black magic?

Comment: Note that best is: `str.splitlines()`

Comment: The `\n` and a literal newline are the same regex escapes matching a newline. Why would you expect any difference?

Comment: The regex engine interprets backslash-n as new-line. That's one of its rules.

Comment: Your input string won't produce either of those results since you have `n\ ` before whatsup

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is both the ASCII escape for newlines *and* the regex escape meaning "match a newline". So in a raw string, used with `re.split`, it looks for it as the regex escape; in a non-raw string, it looks for the literal ASCII character, but either way it finds the newline to split on.